# creating multiple link lists

Tags: java

I am supposed to save content of book in linked list i.e

Each book will have many chapters.so one type of linkedlist will be of chapters .Each chapter will be having many sections.Hence each of the chapter node should point to a list of sections.Each section contains multiple paragraphs.so each of the subtopic node should point to a list of paragraphs..how can i implement this

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like you'd have *something* like:

```
class Book
{
    private final LinkedList<Chapter> chapters;
    // Other stuff
}

class Chapter
{
    private final Linkedist<Section> sections;
    // Other stuff
}

class Section
{
    private final Linkedist<Paragraph> paragraphs;
    // Other stuff
}
```

(You may very well choose to declare the variables themselves to be of type `List<E>` or perhaps `Deque<E>`, using `LinkedList<E>` only when creating the actual objects that the variables refer to. I've only used the concrete type here for brevity.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to make 4 classes :

1. Book
2. Chapter
3. Section
4. Paragraph

The Book class will hold field of type `List<Chapter>`. The Chapter class will hold a field of type `List<Section>`. The Section class will hold a field of type `List<Paragraph>`.